# Sqlite with (CloudKit or iCloud Drive)

Tags: ios, sqlite, cloudkit, icloud-drive

I have an iOS app that timestamps some events and loads them in UI. To persist the data I use CloudKit which is quite fine and fast enough for my use case.

1st problem is, when an event occures I save it instantly to cloudkit therefore if internet is not reachable I have to handle the situation. I had the idea of having a local sqlite db and sort of keep track of connectivity and deal with syncing manually. Here is where 2nd problem comes in in which any inconsistency of the data must be handled by me (e.g. if the user edits the data while offline).

I found YapDatabase library doing the exact things but I feel the learning curve is a little bit steep.

Another idea could be using sqlite db but saving the file in the icloud drive. This way it will be persisted automatically while I have access to the app sqlite. Any change in the db tables will change the file singnature and fire icloud drive sync.

What's the best choice?

Comment: And what about if you use a service like couchbase http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/

Comment: I stumbleupon this today. Where's the pricing?

Comment: Get your own VPS or cloud server. If you had your own server and database there are syncing algorithms you could look up and implement. I would suggest you either get your own Virtual Private Server (VPS) or AWS Server and host the app yourself with your own database and server. It can seem daunting at first,but in the long run it will allow you to be more innovative and flexible with your solutions.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer by database, are you talking about couchdb or any in general?

iCloud solutions allow more privacy and less hassle for user authentication.

Comment: @CPPChase In general. You could use any you want or whatever suits your needs. I'm using a CentOS box with Node.JS HTTPS server and a Mongo Database.

Comment: @CPPChase I started off using Parse.com, but when I realized I could standup my own server and avoid them completely I went ahead and implemented my own server. Anytime you add another layer of abstraction it makes issues harder to diagnose. Naive programmers think there is a easy (magical) solution, but you will notice you are many times sacrificing flexibility and pigeon holing your solutions because of the framework while also adding another layer of indirection.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer You must take care of authentication and other security related services, replication and consistency over multiple nodes for availabilty and responsivness around the world, data encryption to provide privacy and anonymity and a lot more. It's just about time, cost, flexibilty and the risk level you can accept on issues like data loss. I can use available and not so flexible services but I develope free apps for fun and experience and it's a little bit hard to pay for them.

Comment: @CPPChase Fine until one day you actually want to do something serious. You mention all these things that "I must take care", but that's the point. I don't want anyone else taking care of them for me, instead I want to learn how these things work. I like learning as well and don't mind paying $60 a month for a VPS, which is really on the expensive side, because I require root access to my VPS. You can get one for as little as $15 a month. Far too many Developers pigeon-hole themselves into one technology and are lost with anything outside their scope.